# Loop a function or use multiple?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I'm getting some data from a mysql database using ajax, data.one, data.two and data.three. Each with a different string.

I also have three divs, .one .two and .three.

How can I append data.one to the div .one and so on with all three divs and data without repeating a code like this for all three divs?

```
$('.one').append(data.one);
$('.two').append(data.two);
$('.three').append(data.three);
```

My own thought was to make a function that repeats but I don't know how to accomplish that..

I guess this is not a big deal with only three strings and divs but the site I'm building is using more of them and I want the code to look clean.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add sample of data result from ajax request

Comment: Use a function with two input parameters: function `process( divName, data)` and process (loop) over the `data` and add it to `divName`.

Comment: In your script, do you know the count? Like in above example, count will be 3.

Comment: Additionally, I am assuming 21 will be twentyone. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that simple, particular example:

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
    $('.'+key).append(value);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ox6Lnft5/)

Comment: Ok, I got it working using your method, thank you very much!

Comment: How can I assign a key to the values I get from the db? Do I need to create a new object and match them together or is it something I should do in the backend?

Comment: Difficult to answer that, as there're many dependencies. The best option would be to assign them somehow while fetching the data from DB. though.

Comment: My bad.. I think I got it working, somehow! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function like that:

```
function addToElement(key,val) {
 $('.'+key).append(val);   
}
```

And then call it like:

```
$.each(data, addToElement);
```

**Info:** *Since the second parameter of $.each is a callback function, its parameters are automatically filled in by jQuery. You get the key and the value of the current element.*

You could also do it like this:

```
 $.each(data, function(key,val) {
   $('.'+key).append(val);   
 });
```

and don't use a seperate function.

Check this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L72jwrwz/)

Comment: that is a callback.  they are automatically passed using jQuery's `$.each`.  It is the better way of writing `$.each(data, function(key, val) { ... });`

Comment: Ah, I never realised that it took a callback function, my mistake. Up voted.